# Exported objects from passed function are undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to pass a function from a component to an extern component. The function calls a intern created object. The problem is that this object is undefined when the function is called by the extern component.

Is there a way, that this object is still defined, when the function is called?

Internal object:

```
export class CustomClass {
  date: Date;

  constructor() {
    this.date = new Date();
  }
}
```

AppComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<app-custom-control [functionCall]="testFunction"></app-custom-control>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  customClass = new CustomClass();

  constructor() {
    // customClass is defined
    console.log("Uhrzeit: " + this.customClass.date); 
  }

  testFunction(text: string): string {
    //Called in the CustomControl component, this.customClass is undefined
    console.log("CustomClass vorhanden? " + this.customClass);    

    return JSON.stringify(this.customClass);
  }
}
```

Extern Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-control',
  template: `
  <form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
      <mat-label>Example text</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="Text input" value="" (input)="handleInput($event)">
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
  <div>{{result}}</div>`,
  //templateUrl: './custom-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-control.component.scss']
})
export class CustomControlComponent  {

  @Input()
  functionCall: ((text: string) => string) | undefined;
  result: string = '';

  handleInput(value: any) {
    if (this.functionCall) {
      this.result = this.functionCall("value");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in the question you don't have in your real code. `console.log("Uhrzeit: " + customClass.date);` should be `console.log("Uhrzeit: " + this.customClass.date);`

Comment: Thank's for your comment. This is not the problem.
The problem is: If testfunction() is called by CustomControlComponent this.customClass is undefined.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*How to access the correct `this` inside a callback*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) *(already voted to close as typo, because of the typo above, before realizing that wasn't what you were asking about)*

Comment: Yes, I know that's not the problem. (I'd already edited my comment, you may have seen the earlier version.)